# mybatis mapping the class which protobuf generated

Tags: protocol-buffers, mybatis, protobuf-java

How can I map the result to protobuf class in mybatis mapper? There is no set method in protobuf class. Should I generate the entity class by using newBuilder and build method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. In When you are generating the model classes from your proto file each of them are having a Builder (that extends GeneratedMessageV3.Builder). So in your model definition you can add that, like this example:

```
@ResultType(MyProto.Builder.class)
```

This is working in fine when you are using ResultHandler, so there you can invoke the build method, like:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(ResultContext<? extends GeneratedMessageV3.Builder> resultContext) {
    GeneratedMessageV3 proto = resultContext.getResultObject().build(); 
    MyProto myproto = (MyProto)proto;

    // do something with myproto

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick. Let's say you have defined the following protobuf,

```proto
package com.example.protobuf;

message HelloMessage {
  string id;
  uint32 code;
}
```

You can have your `HelloMapper` like this,

```xml
<resultMap id="helloMessageMap" type="com.example.protobuf.HelloMessage">
  <result column="id" property="id_"/>
  <result column="code" property="code_"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectHelloMessage" resultMap="helloMessageMap">
  select id, code from example
</select>
```

Please notice that `id_` and `code_` are used instead of `id` and `code`.